# Difference in calldata and arguments

Tags: solidity

This may be a dumb question, but I'm trying to understand is there a difference re: byte-wise or gas-wise in between using `calldata` and explicitly mentioning arguments. For example, for this struct:

```
struct Book {
    string: title;
    uint256: pages;
}
```

There is a makeBook function. Now, is there any difference in the following ways of writing the function?

```
/// Using calldata
function makeBook(Book calldata book) external {
    newBook = Book(book.title, book.pages);
}

/// Mentioning arguments
function makeBook(string title, uint256 pages) external {
    newBook = Book(title, pages);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can think calldata is a special type of argument that can be used in external functions and can not be modifiable.
If you do not use keyword memory or calldata, that argument can be considered as storage.
The main difference between calldata(memory) and storage is the lifetime of the variable.